# How to include table data and push between objects without any foreign key relation

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have following structure of tables

TableA --> TableB (FK with tableA) --> TableC(FK with tableB)

TableX --> TableY(FK with tableX and another FK with tableC)

I am using .NET core EF scaffold and generated classes, there is no direct relation between TableC and TableX classes

```
public partial class TableA
    {
        public TableA()
        {
            TableB = new HashSet<TableB>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }     
        public ICollection<TableB> TableB { get; set; }

    }

 public partial class TableB
    {
        public TableB()
        {
            TableC = new HashSet<TableC>();
        }
        //Other prop

        public Users tableA { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TableC> tableC { get; set; }

    }

 public partial class TableC
    {
        public TableC()
        {
            tableY = new HashSet<TableY>();
        }
        //Other prop
        public TableB tableB { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TableY> tableY { get; set; }

    }

 public partial class TableY
    {
        //Other prop
        public TableC tableC { get; set; }
        public TableX tableX { get; set; }
    }

   public partial class TableX
    {   
        public TableX()
        {
            tableX = new HashSet<TableX>();
        }
        //Other prop
        public ICollection<TableX> tableX { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using below query

```
_context.TableA.Where(x => x.Email == email.Trim())
                        .Include(i => i.TableB )
                        .ThenInclude(k => k.TableC)
                        .ThenInclude(l => l.TableY)
```

I am missing the TableX from object chain and looking for a query which can make TableX as a child object of TableC, like as bellow

TableA --> TableB --> TableC --> TableX --> TableY

when I am using below query

```
 _context.TableA.Where(x => x.Email == email.Trim())
                            .Include(i => i.TableB )
                            .ThenInclude(k => k.TableC)
                            .ThenInclude(l => l.TableY.Select(g => g.tableX))
```

I am getting error

ArgumentException: The Include property lambda expression 'p => p.Reservations' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter of the target type, E.g. '(Derived d) => d.MyProperty'.

Comment: Why not `.ThenInclude(y => y.X)`?

Comment: there is no property generated within tableC for tacbleX  by scaffold

Comment: That's not what I ask. There should be a property `TableY.TableX`. The syntax `l.TableY.Select(g => g.tableX)` in invalid in ef-core includes.

Comment: VS 2017 Intellisense unable to find TableY.TableX though it has the property. I am getting error ICollection<tableY> does not contain a definition for tableX no accesible extension method accepting a first argument of type ICollection<tableY> ...

Comment: Time for a [mcve].

Comment: updated Q. There is no direct relation between X and C , I want after C , i can get objects from X and then Y

Comment: There is an access path from `A` to `X`: A-B-C-Y-X so, from C, you *have* to access `X` through `Y`. No other way. How would you imagine a SQL query do what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to access X through Y only but first X and then Y object. Is this possible with any EF query. Like Y -> X -> Y. Actually X is kind of static ( master table ) data